# Google Chrome: refresh duplicate tab

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, refresh

When I duplicate a tab in google chrome(65) it will use a cached version from the existing tab and I need it to go to the server and get the newer configuration from it.

So is there a way to force chrome to go to the server?

**Note** : In case of refreshing the current page it will go to the server and get the newer configuration from it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. So I found a workaround solution as there were no direct methods to detect if a tab is duplicated.

Making an Ajax call to the controller in `$(document).ready()` and fetching the latest configuration values fixed it. So whether the page is refreshed or opened as a duplicate tab, it will always make the Ajax call on page load.

**Note:** I was dealing with a single page only, so this solution was feasible for me.